# i want a regex which satisfy the following conditions

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Conditions are as follows:

1 I not only between 1 to 99.99
2 decimal limit up to two decimal places

Comment: Sorry `I want ...` is not the way this platform works. You show your attempt first then people will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

After going through to various regex and testing them i got the following solution.

[0-9]{0,2}((.[0-9]{0,2}))?